# compile time error in JPA named query xml file .error-"Multiple annotations found at this line"

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jpa, named-query

I am getting compile time error in my jpa_named_queries.xml as follows:

1. The SELECT clause has 'function' and '('DATE', obj.authTime) AS dateAuth' that are not separated by a comma.
2. The identification variable 'function' is not defined in the FROM clause.

My queries:

```
<named-query name="XXAuthSession.getUserLoggedIn">
  <!--error in this query -->
  <query>SELECT count(obj),function('DATE',obj.authTime) as dateAuth FROM XXAuthSession obj GROUP BY dateAuth</query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="XXAuthSession.getAuthSessionBySessionId">
  <!-- this query is working fine -->
  <query>SELECT obj FROM XXAuthSession obj WHERE obj.extSessionId= :sessionId</query>
</named-query>
```

Comment: Never seen `function('DATE',obj.authTime) as dateAuth`, what do you intend to achieve ?

Comment: "function" is JPA 2.1 standard, allowing invocation of a SQL function. Perhaps you haven't set the XSD validation at the top of the XML file correct? Ought to be using JPA 2.1

Comment: While you're at it, please enlighten us as to what is this file "jpa_named_queries.xml" because JPA has no such file. So what requires it?

Comment: @NeilStockton : thanks, I didn't know about this feature :)

Comment: jpa_named_query is the file , where i have kept all my queries and i am accessing them from java program ( inside DAO layer)